# Multiple schema JSON validation in Golang

Tags: json, go, jsonschema

I need to validate several `JSON` files against a schema in `Golang`.

I have been able to achieve it by using [gojsonschema](https://github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema), that is really a straight forward library.

However, the problem I'm facing right now is that I have been given with schemas that have dependencies to another schemas and haven't found the way to load all the schemas that I need. Therefore, my validations always fail.

This is my main schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "$ref": "#/definitions/List",
    "definitions": {
        "List": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/Item"
            }
        },
        "Item": {
            "description": "An item ....",
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "property01": {
                    "description": "The property01 code.",
                    "$ref": "./CommonTypes.json#/definitions/Type01Definition"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "property01"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And, I have another one with common types:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "definitions": {
        "Type01Definition": {
            "description": "The definition for the type 01",
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^[A-Z0-9]{3}$"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to load several schemas using that library? Or is there any other `Golang` library that allows to achieve that?

Comment: The second question is off-topic for SO: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to refer to a file using `$ref` is to specify the absolute path of the file using a URL scheme. If you change the `$ref` to look like `"$ref" : "file:///home/user/directory/CommonTypes.json#/definitions/Type01Definition`, your example will work as expected.

If you need a bit more flexibility you can either try `gojsonschema`'s [NewReferenceLoaderFilesystem](https://godoc.org/github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema#NewReferenceLoaderFileSystem) or switch to a different `Golang` library https://github.com/santhosh-tekuri/jsonschema. That library allows you to add custom resources so you can load several schemas at once.